# Jquery data Attribute conditional Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get all DOM which attribute data-"value" in grater then 100 and less then 500

```
<div id="bg1" data-50="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;"></div>
<div id="bg2" data-200="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -8000px;"></div>
<div id="bg3" data-300="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -6000px;"></div>    
<div id="bg4" data-600="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;"></div>
<div id="bg5" data-150="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -8000px;"></div>
<div id="bg6" data-800="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -6000px;"></div>
```

Comment: what is reason for using different key for each  numeric attribute? Wouldn't it make more sense to have same key for each element for the background and add a different attribute for the number?

Comment: there is no simple selector, or even a very simple filter  for what you are asking because of the way you have set up the data attributes. It can be done using filter() but would need more information on what the numeric keys might be. What are you trying to do with this markup?

Comment: This smells like an xy problem. You'll probably get a way better solution if you explain what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @charlietfl    I found this concept at here http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `data-*` attributes. All the attribute selectors filter the elements by their attribute's *value* not but their attribute's *name*. There is no predefined selector here. You could iterate through the `attributes` and do it the hard way:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    var a = this.attributes, l = a.length, n;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
       if ( a[i].name.match(/^data-[0-9]+$/) ) {
           n = + a[i].name.replace('data-', '');
           return n > 100 && n < 500;
       }
    }
    return false;    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonpom9m/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following example:

in the following example i assume that there are only 2 data attributes, and one of them is 'data-end'

```
$(function () {
    //we go through all of the dom elements:
    $("*").each(function () {
        //here we go through all of the attributes of the current element:
        $.each(this.attributes, function () {
            //if the attribute containts "data" in its name, and doesnt contain "end", then
            //its an attribute that we need. if you have more data attributes, you need
            //to filter them in the following condition as well:
            if (this.name.indexOf("data") > -1 && 
                this.name.indexOf("end")==-1) {
                //we extract the number from the data attribute:
                var lenght = this.name.length;
                var number_from_data=this.name.substring(5,lenght);
                var is_it_between_100_and_500;
                if(number_from_data>100 && number_from_data<500){
                    is_it_between_100_and_500=true;
                }
                else{
                    is_it_between_100_and_500=false;
                }
                console.log(this.name,is_it_between_100_and_500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/9pewgy2g/)**</kbd>

Comment: Going through *all* DOM elements is almost always overkill. Something like `$("[id^=bg]")` ought to work better here.

Comment: i thought about that, but after having a 2nd look at his question i spotted the "How can i get all DOM"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a double filtering to retrieve the elements with attribute `data-[number]` having `number > 100 and number < 500`. Still, if we knew more about what you are trying to do, I suspect a much simpler solution would be possible.

[**Edit**] added a simpler method using the elements `outerHTML` string for filtering

```js
// FilterDivs: double filtering on attributes nodelist
// FilterDivs2: filter using a match in the outerHTML-string
// ----------------------------------------------------------
var filteredDivs = 
    $('[data-end]').filter( function (i, el) {
       return [].slice.call(el.attributes).filter(
           function (v) {
              var key = v.nodeName
                       ,isdatanum = /data\-\d/i.test(key)
                       ,val = isdatanum && +key.split('-')[1] || 0;
              return val > 100 && val < 500;
           }).length
     })
   ,filteredDivs2 = $('[data-end]').filter( function (i, el) {
         var number = +(el.outerHTML.match(/data-(\d+)=/) || [0,0])[1];
         return number > 100 && number < 500;
     });
//show result
$('#result').html('filteredDivs: '+
                  filteredDivs.toArray()
                   .map(function (v) {return '[div#'+v.id+']';}) +
                  ' (see console for actual elements)');
$('#result2').html('filteredDivs2: '+
                  filteredDivs2.toArray()
                   .map(function (v) {return '[div#'+v.id+']';}) +
                  ' (see console for actual elements)');
// log to console
console.log(filteredDivs);
console.log(filteredDivs2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg1" data-50="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;"></div>
<div id="bg2" data-200="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -8000px;"></div>
<div id="bg3" data-300="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -6000px;"></div>    
<div id="bg4" data-600="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;"></div>
<div id="bg5" data-150="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -8000px;"></div>
<div id="bg6" data-800="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -6000px;"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
// return `filtered` array of `DOM` elememts  
// having `data-*` `key` greater than `rangeStart` and less than `rangeStop`
var elem = $("div")
, rangeStart = 100
, rangeStop = 500
, filtered = elem.filter(function(i, el) {
    var _range = Number( Object.keys( $(el).data() || el.dataset )[0] );
    return ( _range > rangeStart && _range < rangeStop )
}).get();
```

```js
var elem = $("div")
, rangeStart = 100
, rangeStop = 500
, filtered = elem.filter(function(i, el) {
    var _range = Number( Object.keys( $(el).data() || el.dataset )[0] );
    return ( _range > rangeStart && _range < rangeStop )
}).get();

filtered.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.color = "blue"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg1" data-50="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;">50</div>
<div id="bg2" data-200="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -8000px;">200</div>
<div id="bg3" data-300="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -6000px;">300</div>    
<div id="bg4" data-600="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;">600</div>
<div id="bg5" data-150="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -8000px;">150</div>
<div id="bg6" data-800="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -6000px;">800</div>
```